# Apex:OutputText to Currency Format from String Wrapper

Tags: visualforce, table, outputtext

is there a way to pass a string to the `<apex:outputText>` so that it can be formatted as a currency or percent value?

Here's what I have inside a column of my visual force table:

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, number, currecny}">
<apex:param value="{!row.values[1]}" />
</apex:outputText
```

this gives me an error at runtime (when the visual force page loads), which I think may be some kind of type mismatch, where `<apex:outputText>` is expecting a Decimal or number but I am passing a string.

This is the error at runtime:

> The value attribute on  is not in a valid format. It must be a positive number, and of type Number, Date, Time, or Choice.

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem was you misspelled currency. This works fine and avoids hard coding the currency symbol:

`<apex:outputText value="{0, Number, Currency}">`

Answer (score 12):

From my comment:

`<apex:outputText value="${0, number, ###,###,##0.00}">` works as well. The hashes display numbers in that position if they exist. So it will display $3.14 instead of $000,003.14 as in the example using `${0, number, 000,000.00}`

Answer (score 7):

You need to use `<apex param>` along with `<apex:outputText>` by specifying the proper parameters for it to be output in. Here's an example from the VF Developer's Guide:

```
<!-- For this example to render properly, you must associate the Visualforce page
with a valid account record in the URL.
For example, if 001D000000IeChM is the account ID, the resulting URL should be:
https://Salesforce_instance/apex/myPage?id=001D000000IeChM
See the Visualforce Developer's Guide Quick Start Tutorial for more information. -->

<apex:page standardController="Account">
It is worth:
<apex:outputText value="{0, number, 000,000.00}">
<apex:param value="{!Account.AnnualRevenue}" />
</apex:outputText>
</apex:page>
```

This would render as

```
It is worth: 500,000,000.00
```

Were I doing this, I'd be adding the currency symbol in with the outputText value as below:

```
<apex:outputText value="$&nbsp{0, number, 000,000.00}">
```

This would render as

```
It is worth: $500,000,000.00
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what advice you are supplying that I do not already know.

I am using both of the tags.

Comment: You've specified it as `{0, number, currecny}` (a typo on your part for currency) and more importantly, not as `{0, number, 000.00}` <--- display format for the number!

Comment: Yes the typo is there (but not in my code).  {0, number, currency} is in fact valid, though.

Comment: It turns out I have been able to answer my own question. As I thought, apex:param cannot take a string, as it expects a number and will not do any sort of type conversion, so a string wrapper class will not work with this.  Instead I created a generic object wrapper class and it works wonderfully.  Will update the answer when stack exchange allows it.

Comment: Your issue would seem to be related to your wrapper class and not to `apex:param` which can take a string. According to the VF Developer's Guide, the value attribute can be set to a `string, number, or boolean` value.

Comment: Yeah, but I am not so sure, from observation of this experience, that apex:param or apex:outputText do in fact support strings.

Comment: I suspect a String is valid when the output format is a String, in this case the output format clearly specifies a number hence the mismatch. That said, the error message could be more useful!

Comment: For completeness, `<apex:outputText value="${0, number, ###,###,##0.00}">` works as well.  The hashtags display numbers in that position if they exist.  So it will display `$3.14` instead of `$000,003.14` as in the example using `${0, number, 000,000.00}`.

Comment: @ʞɐʃǝԀʇʇoɔS, You should post your comment as answer to this question. It is very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Best Solution for the above problem is:

```
<apex:outputText label="NRR" value="{0,number}">
{! Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode} &nbsp;
<apex:param value="{! Opportunity.NRR__c}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

This is give you the Currency (CurrencyIsoCode) as well as the value (in proper format) if it exists in the field value.