# Is there any predefined methods to display currency in VF pages different countries?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, jquery

For USA - $ 1,000,000,000.00
For India - Rs 1,00,00,000.00

I Know this is possible by using java script regular expressions.If we are using java script,we need to write regex for each country.But I want to know that "Is it possible by using salesforce predefined methods(if any) ?"

Comment: Are those currency field? or you want to display currency based on logged in users location?

Comment: Thanks for your response.It is a currency type field.Our application is force.com site.Please tell me how to display currency symbol and currency format based on logged in users location?

Comment: But what about the conversion, as $ 1,000,000,000.00 is not equal to Rs 1,00,00,000.00.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a knowledge article from Salesforce to do it

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000176332&language=en_US

```
<apex:page > 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        var __sfdcSessionId = '{!GETSESSIONID()}'; 
    </script> 
    <script src="../../soap/ajax/27.0/connection.js"    type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        window.onload = setupPage; 
        function setupPage() { 
            var result = sforce.connection.getUserInfo(); 

            alert(result); 
            document.getElementById('label').innerHTML=result.currencySymbol; 

            log("Output:" + output); 
    } 
    </script> 
    <div id="label"> </div> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: By using above code ,we are getting only symbol of currency.But I need to change the format of currency. Ex: USA - $ 1,000,000,000.00                         For India - Rs 1,00,00,000.00

Comment: This can by done by dynamically passing last parameter in outputText <apex:outputText value="{0, number, 000,000.00}">
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44748/apexoutputtext-to-currency-format-from-string-wrapper