# Currency Format in Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I am trying  to change the currency format to below format

Netherlands - EUR ###.##0,00 :

Code which I am using:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account"> 
    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, 000,000.00}"> 
        <apex:param value="{!Account.AnnualRevenue}" /> 
    </apex:outputText> 
</apex:page>
```

However , It is throwing

> invalid format

error. Please assist

Answer (score 2):

Looks like [this can help](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44748/apexoutputtext-to-currency-format-from-string-wrapper) you:
`<apex:outputText value="{0, Number, Currency}">` You can also try `{0, number, EUR #.##0,00}`

Comment: FYI, the format `#.##0,00` does not work as it is not a valid message format. There doesn't appear to be a way to change the decimal and thousands separator using the standard out of the box visualforce (without a dirty hack)

Answer (score 1):

Java MessageFormat applied as `000,000.00` supports US currency and date formats. There is an [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bqq9) here you can vote on as it asks for specific tag for currency.

**Workarounds:**

1. Use `<apex:outputField>` as it will obey the locale settings of the currently logged in user. But it will work only if you are referencing a SObject.
2. Format the currency in Apex and show the formatted value in Visualforce.

Comment: Is there any reference code ? I have tried but still not working

Comment: Can you try `<apex:outputField value="{!Account.AnnualRevenue}" />`