# 3 Column page layout on Custom Object

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to create a visualforce page for a Custom object but I am getting an error on the VF page: Error: Syntax error. Found 'Sales_Rebate__c.'
I am trying to create a VF to allow for 3 columns on the page layout.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.
M

```
<apex:page standardController="Sales_Rebate__c">
   <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock title="Early Buy Percentages"> 
           <apex:pageBlockSection title="My Section" columns="3" collapsible="true">
                <apex:outputField value="{!Sales_Rebate__c. Growth_Tier_1_1__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!Sales_Rebate__c. Growth_Tier_1_2__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!Sales_Rebate__c. Growth_Tier_1_3__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!Sales_Rebate__c.Growth_Tier_2_1__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!Sales_Rebate__c.Growth_Tier_2_2__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!Sales_Rebate__c.Growth_Tier_2_3__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!Sales_Rebate__c. Growth_Tier_3_1__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!Sales_Rebate__c. Growth_Tier_3_2__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!Sales_Rebate__c. Growth_Tier_3_3__c}"/>
              </apex:pageBlockSection> 
         </apex:pageBlock> 
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few spaces after this `Sales_Rebate__c.` in `<apex:outputField>`. That's why the issue is occurring.

Regarding 3 columns display, you can use `<apex:PanelGrid>`.

Refer my answer to this question [4 columns on a custom visual force inline page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/136500/4-columns-on-a-custom-visual-force-inline-page/136518#136518)

Comment: Snatanu, you are correct and my code works now but it does not show in 'edit' mode.  Why is that?  Thanks M

Comment: Please update your question and what is not working?

Comment: I will close this question and ask a new one.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
        .dataCol{
            width:0.5rem !important;
        }
    </style>

    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection collapsible="true" columns="6"> 
<apex:OutputField value="{!contact.Other_Musculoskeletal_Disorders__c}" rendered="{!contact.Other_Musculoskeletal_Disorders__c}"/>
                <apex:OutputField value="{!contact.Joint_Replacement__c}" rendered="{!contact.Joint_Replacement__c}"/> 
                <apex:OutputField  value="{!contact.Food_Allergies__c}" rendered="{!contact.Food_Allergies__c}"/> 
                <apex:OutputField value="{!contact.Medicine_Allergies__c}" rendered="{!contact.Medicine_Allergies__c}"/> 
                <apex:OutputField   value="{!contact.Seasonal_Environmental_Allergies__c}" rendered="{!contact.Seasonal_Environmental_Allergies__c}"/>
                <apex:OutputField   value="{!contact.known_genetic_mutation__c}" rendered="{!contact.known_genetic_mutation__c}"/>
                <apex:OutputField value="{!contact.necessary_treatment_in_future__c}" rendered="{!contact.necessary_treatment_in_future__c}"/>

        </apex:pageBlockSection>

</apex:pageBlock>
```