# Comma Between Numbers-VF Page

Tags: apex, visualforce

Comma Between Numbers Example: 300000 to 3,00,000
Here is My code below:

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, number, #, ###}">
  <apex:param value="{!ROUND(number,0)}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

Comment: Have you checked this thread [Apex:OutputText to Currency Format from String Wrapper](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44748/apexoutputtext-to-currency-format-from-string-wrapper)

Comment: Thanks for reply, it's not working fine

Comment: `not` working fine or `now` working fine?  If you solved it, add an answer

Comment: not working fine, I want to split them currency value with a comma, Example 8527388 to 85,27,388 but below code splits the value like this 8,52,73,88.       Apex Class:

public Double total { get; set; }
total = sum + gst;
VF Page:

<apex:outputText value="{0, number, #,##,###,##}">
                                    <apex:param value="{!ROUND(total,0)}" />
                                </apex:outputText>