# Visualforce Custom Currency format

Tags: apex, visualforce, currency, outputtext

I have a formula Currency field. My customer wants below format.

```
1.000,00 €

599,40 €

85,00 €

1,00 €
```

I tried using the below format and this is not exactly what I am looking for.

```
<apex:outputText value="${0, number, ###,###,###,##0.00}">
    <apex:param value="{!quot1.Ancillary_Weekly_Charge_Total__c}" />
</apex:outputText> €
```

What changes should I do to the above code or How can I populate the exact format?

Answer (score 1):

Using the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputText.htm) and a little bit of research I made this example and tested using Opportunity object along with its Amount field.

And also special thanks to @Scott Pelak for his comment from this [thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44748/apexoutputtext-to-currency-format-from-string-wrapper). Where he explained the usage of ###,###,##0.00 very well.

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,###,##0.00}">
     <apex:param value="{!Opportunity.Amount}" />
</apex:outputText>
<apex:outputText> €</apex:outputText>
```

Or you could also use the tag like this. Thanks to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33384318/how-to-use-nbsp-in-html5):

```
<pre>
    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,###,##0.00}">
        <apex:param value="{!Opportunity.Amount}" />
    </apex:outputText> €
</pre>
```

I noticed for me using the ***pre*** tag changes formatting a little bit. Please change the code above to fit your requirement :)
Hope it helps.